# Material UI Datagrid : React does not recognize the `focusElementRef` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I am working with a Material UI React DataGrid Component using the following code

```
const EditApplication = React.useCallback(
  (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    console.log(id);
  },
  []
);

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'application',
    headerName: 'Application Name',
    width: 400,
    minWidth: 200,
    maxWidth: 1000,
    headerClassName: 'header weight-700',
  },
  {
    width: 400,
    minWidth: 200,
    maxWidth: 1000,
    field: 'actions',
    headerName: 'Action',
    type: 'actions',
    headerClassName: 'header weight-700',

    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <p
          onClick={EditApplication(params.id)}
          className='cta weight-700 click-command'
        >
          Edit
        </p>
      );
    },
  },
];

const rows: any[] = [];

applications.map((applicationDetail: application) => {
  rows.push({
    id: applicationDetail.id,
    application: applicationDetail.applicationName,
  });
});
```

I am then passing this into a reusable component like this

```
<DatagridContainer columns={columns} rowData={rows} pageSize={10} />
```

And this rednders on the page like this

```
export function DatagridContainer({ columns, rowData, pageSize }: Props) {
  return (
    <DataGrid
      autoHeight
      initialState={{
        pagination: {
          paginationModel: { pageSize: pageSize, page: 0 },
        },
      }}
      disableColumnSelector={true}
      rows={rowData}
      columns={columns}
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

When I click the edit button this gives out the information I expect. However, I get a console error \ warning like this

> Warning: React does not recognize the `focusElementRef` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `focuselementref` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
> at p

[image]

When I remove the Action field and the render cell, the error goes away.  My Question is, what have I done wrong or missed in order for this warning \ error to be thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the culprit to the problem

```
type: 'actions',
```

in

```
{
 width: 400,
 minWidth: 200,
 maxWidth: 1000,
 field: 'actions',
 headerName: 'Action',
 type: 'actions',
 headerClassName: 'header weight-700',

 renderCell: (params) => {
   return (
     <p
       onClick={EditApplication(params.id)}
       className='cta weight-700 click-command'
     >
       Edit
     </p>
   );
  },
},
```

Removing this has solved the issue

Comment: This does not fix the issue. The "action" type column is a special column with associated features. If you remove the type, you will lose them.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this same issue. The issue with the actions column is that you should use `getActions` rather than `renderCell`.  This fixed the issue for me.

```
const columns: GridColDef<MyDataType>[] = [
{
  ...dateColumnConfig,
  headerName: 'Date',
  field: 'date'
},
{
  ...actionsColumnConfig,
  getActions: (params: GridRowParams) => [
    <Chip
      icon={<TocIcon />}
      label="Contents"
      onClick={() => {
        /*do something*/
      }}
    />
  ]
} as GridActionsColDef<MyDataType>
```

If you're using typescript you'll need to cast the `GridColDef` to a `GridActionsColDef` in order for it to recognise the `getActions` prop.  This is version 5, so may have been fixed in v6 - but we haven't upgraded yet.

Comment: This is the proper answer, not the one which is accepted right now!